# Serial communication between PC and Arduino using C

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, c, ubuntu

I'm trying to send some data to my arduino mega 2560 using serial communication.

I'm using the exemple that I found [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=178913.0) without success.

Every site I read say that I can send data to the arduino board like writing to any file on ubuntu.

But I alway get `Segmentation fault`

**Here is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char arduinoPort[] = "/dev/ttyACM0";

int main() {

  char buffer[] = {'1'};

  FILE *usb_port;

  usb_port = fopen(arduinoPort, "rwb");

  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), usb_port);

  fclose(usb_port);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you not using the arduino IDE?

Comment: @jsotola, because they write for PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program works flawlessly on my Ubuntu 18.04. I would guess that you
have a problem with your setup (flaky USB port, permission problems...)
rather than the program itself. Still, I would recommend you add some
error checking: right after the `fopen()` call,

```cpp
if (!usb_port) {
    perror(arduinoPort);
    return 1;
}
```

I would expect you see something like

```
/dev/ttyACM0: No such file or directory
```

or

```
/dev/ttyACM0: Permission denied
```

that could help you pin down the real problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. It wasn't working because i opened the serial monitor and because the message i could see it. When serial monitor is opened the serial is busy.